# Does clojure supports method overloading by return type?

Tags: clojure, overloading

I was reading some storm code when I've stumbled upon [this two functions](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/blob/0.9.0/src/clj/backtype/storm/scheduler/IsolationScheduler.clj#L21). They're identical by both name and parameters, but looks like they differ in return type. **Slightly** simplified code is:

```
(defn- foo "Returns list of sets of things"
  [^Bar xs]
  (->> ...
       (map set)))

(defn- foo "Returns mutable set of sets of things"
  [^Bar xs]
  (->> ...
       (map set)
       (HashSet.)
       ))
```

Can anybody shed some light on what is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second definition overwrites the first one. Clojure doesn't care for types.

Comment: Hmmm, wondering why this was written in a such way: [both functions were introduced in the same commit](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/commit/d44970afeb3f6166b6c93b6ce39e5cb49b615114#L1R21) so [for me] it is unlikely that author just forgot to wipe out former one.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Well, I don't know the intention of the original author but I can tell you what happens. :]

Comment: @om-nom-nom That sort of thing is easy to overlook in REPL-based development. You can re-def vars to your heart's content and the compiler won't issue any sort of warning, so once you write the second version it's easy to forget the first is there.